# When does Microsoft stop supporting Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

When will Silverlight support [from Microsoft] be officially end-of-lifed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft will support Silverlight until 12 Oct 2021:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/lifecycle?c2=12905

> Support for releases known as Tools ends no less than 12 months following the notification date. Silverlight 5 will support the browser versions listed on [this page](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=236043) through 10/12/2021, or though the support lifecycle of the underlying browsers, whichever is shorter. As browsers evolve, the support page will be updated to reflect levels of compatibility with newer browser versions.

If you have investigated Silverlight thoroughly and come to the conclusion that it is the right technology for your project you should use it.

Comment: I am not looking in context of "Support" to silverlight. Does microsoft going to have new addition to silverlight. I have refferred lot of links, most of them saying XAML will be there but silverlight will be dead. http://hal2020.com/2012/02/13/silverlight-is-dead-long-live-xaml/

Comment: No one knows for sure if there is going to be a Silverlight 6, but it seems highly unlikely given that everything is going in the direction of HTML 5, like Win8. My guess is that there will be a minor service pack at some point but that Silverlight 6 is never going to happen. But that is just a guess. As Rumplin said in his answer, Silverlight is the way to go if it is a project where you know that all users will have (or at least can install) Silverlight. If the project is a public facing web site that needs to support mobile browsers, IPads etc. Silverlight is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: So to answer your specific question my answer would be no: MS will not add any substantial features to Silverlight. At least it seems highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Don't upgrade to Silverlight, the future is HTML5 (plus CSS3 and javascript of course)!

Comment: We were developing with Silverlight 4 in a huge project for about 1 year, and we are planning to transform it to HTML5 :(
Note: Silverlight (and Flash as well) may have more features now than HTML5, but, for sure, HTML5 will lead!

Comment: Heard that too many times before during the past 15 years.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is ok, especially if you are inside an intranet with older browsers, otherwise if you are doing the project for the internet go with HTML5.

Silverlight will be supported until 2021. 
As for new releases of Silverlight, it's unclear if there will be a Silverligh 6 version.

The knowledge you will gain with Silverlight(XAML) is in your advantage as Metro apps use XAML code too.